# Cannot reference a Xamarin.Mac library which is targetting Xamarin.Mac Full

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm currently trying to build a Xamarin.Mac project, and at this point I need to switch to Xamarin.Mac full.

I have two projects in my solution, both targeting Xamarin.Mac Modern, which has worked perfectly for now. After switching to Xamarin.Mac Full .NET Framework 4.5, I cannot complile my application. Compiling the library works perfectly, but when compiling my application I get the following error:

```
/Solution/ExecutableProject/MMP: Error MM1407: Mismatch between Xamarin.Mac reference
'/Solution/LibraryProject/bin/Debug/LibraryProject.dll' and target framework selected
'Xamarin.Mac,Version=v4.5,Profile=Full'. (MM1407) (ExecutableProject)
```

Both projects are targeting Xamarin.Mac Full .NET Framework 4.5. I have tried Xamarin.Mac Unsupported 4.5 but same issue.

As a work around I have imported the library contents into the application project which compiles fine, but I would rather not have to do this.
Wondering if anyone has run into this problem and has a solution?

Cheers,
David

Comment: Can you post the full project xml for both (csproj)? There is probably some subtle mismatch. That, and also try doing a hard clean of everything and rebuilding from scratch (i.e. git clean -xdf assuming it's under version control).